# txt file import issues in R

Tags: r, filter, grepl, txt

The issue is that the txt files themselves appear to be poorly formatted, however I can't get anything to work once they are in the R environment to transform the data into a workable format (i.e. data frame with one entry per column).

The base R function `read.delim` imports my text files as a single column (ignoring the delimiter which I am not sure if it is tab or space). I have tried:

```
indivs<-lapply(files, read.delim, sep="\t", header=T, na.strings = "NA")
```

which gives the undesired result as described (single column with all values separated by space or tab as a long character string)

I have also tried:

```
indivs<-lapply(files, read.delim, sep=" ", header=T, na.strings = "NA")
```

which throws:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

So I thought at least the first option gets the file into R and I could go from there...

The data is from GPS trackers which are prone to getting false readings which causes the column number/header discrepancy because it doesn't give as many values when it is not sure of the location (see data structure at end also). It gives an entry like this:

```
356   356  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/12  13:40:11
```

Full entries look like this:

```
357   357          Valid   5/6  19/12/12  13:50:11  19/12/12  13:48:33.831    -97.169    -23.44309    151.91783        35.04    10.8         0.9             0.0        0.00
```

Using the method in which I actually managed to import the files I have been trying with combinations of `dplyr::filter` and `grepl` with the idea to remove the rows with false readings leaving me with the correct number of heading names and entries allowing a proper `read.delim` execution

I am working with a list of data frames for different trackers so I would prefer  if someone can find a way to apply a solve using a `lapply` function or similar, something like this (doesn't run):

```
    cleaned.txts<-lapply(indivs, function(x){
  x%>%
    filter(grepl("Valid ", .))
})
```

Here is a sample from one of the data frames:

```
    > head(indivs[1])
[[1]]
    Index.........Status..Sats..RTC.date..RTC.time..FIX.date......FIX.time...Delta.s......Latitude....Longitude..Altitude.m.....HDOP........eRes..Temperature.C...Voltage.V.
1       1  NotEnoughSats   0/0  19/12/10  02:30:06                            -81.140                                                                        0.0        0.00
2       2  NotEnoughSats   0/0  19/12/10  02:40:06                            -81.160                                                                        0.0        0.00
3       3  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  02:50:08                            -81.180                                                                        0.0        0.00
4       4  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  03:00:08                            -81.200                                                                        0.0        0.00
5       5  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  03:10:08                            -81.220                                                                        0.0        0.00
6       6  NotEnoughSats   0/0  19/12/10  03:20:06                            -81.240                                                                        0.0        0.00
7       7  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  03:30:08                            -81.260                                                                        0.0        0.00
8       8          Valid   3/3  19/12/10  03:40:11  19/12/10  03:38:49.720    -81.280    -23.44205    151.91308        30.00     2.9         0.0             0.0        0.00
9       9  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  03:50:08                            -81.300                                                                        0.0        0.00
10     10  NotEnoughSats   0/0  19/12/10  04:00:06                            -81.320                                                                        0.0        0.00
11     11  NotEnoughSats   0/0  19/12/10  04:10:06                            -81.340                                                                        0.0        0.00
12     12  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  04:20:08                            -81.360                                                                        0.0        0.00
13     13  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  04:30:08                            -81.380                                                                        0.0        0.00
14     14  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  04:40:08                            -81.400                                                                        0.0        0.00
15     15  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  04:50:08                            -81.420                                                                        0.0        0.00
16     16  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  05:00:08                            -81.440                                                                        0.0        0.00
17     17  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  05:10:08                            -81.460                                                                        0.0        0.00
18     18  NotEnoughSats   0/2  19/12/10  05:20:08                            -81.480                                                                        0.0        0.00
19     19  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  05:30:08                            -81.500                                                                        0.0        0.00
20     20  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  05:40:08                            -81.520                                                                        0.0        0.00
21     21  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  05:50:08                            -81.540                                                                        0.0        0.00
22     22          Valid   5/5  19/12/10  06:00:11  19/12/10  05:58:49.467    -81.533    -23.44350    151.91756        58.28     1.5         0.8             0.0        0.00
23     23  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  06:10:08                            -81.580                                                                        0.0        0.00
24     24          Valid   3/3  19/12/10  06:20:11  19/12/10  06:18:49.400    -81.600    -23.43780    151.92362        58.35   219.5         0.0             0.0        0.00
25     25  NotEnoughSats   0/1  19/12/10  06:30:08                            -81.720                                                                        0.0        0.00
```

Comment: So, a tracker that has some good readings might still give you a "short" header with less column names than what is actually in the data?

Comment: Please add sample file as plain text.

Comment: Maybe try cmd with data.table::fread? Something like: `indivs<-lapply(files, function(i){ fread(paste("grep Valid", i)})`

Comment: Also, if you go by `read.table(file, sep="", skip=1, header=F, fill=T)`, does it still crash?

Comment: I wonder if this is fixed width data, in which case have a look at `read.fwf`.

Comment: Another way of solving this problem if @AndrewGustar's suggestion doesn't work is to replace all of the white-space with commas and import the file using a csv helper.

Comment: @alex_jwb90 to your first question, not exactly. The header remains the same for each file. However some rows are "short" when satellites can't be reached. It doesn't fill them in with NA or other characters so I think that is causing the issue

Comment: @alex_jwb90 to your suggstion for reading in the files with read.table it gives basically the same complaint Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : more columns than column names

Comment: sounds weird that this would even come up when you've explicitly told the reader to ignore headers and fill rows with <NA> if they fall short. can you by any chance add your raw data, or at least an excerpt (incl. headers and some rows, short & long) that allows to replicate the error?

Comment: I ran it again and got it to work, not sure why I got that error but it looks better. However now I get a data frame with only 8 columns meaning the "Valid" entries go over two rows. Not sure if that is clear? I got a similar result when I tried your code below

Comment: yeah, I understand what you mean. can you identify the file and row in which that happens and check whether those have a line break where it shouldn't be or whether R is to blame in this instance?

Comment: It is ok I found the solution thanks to the comment I upvoted above. just tweaked it a little. indivs<-lapply(files, read.table, sep="", header=T, fill=T) then indiv2<-lapply(indivs, filter, Status=="Valid"). you can edit your answer accordingly and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: added it. I had already written down some updated code to read your files in a way robust to unexpected line breaks. if you still need it, hope it helps & works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// UPDATE:
OP's problem is solved simply with:

```
indivs <- lapply(files, read.table, sep="", header=T, fill=T)
indiv2 <- lapply(indivs, filter, Status=="Valid")
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Would this work?
It does for me, assuming that extra columns are added at the end when your tracker has GPS reading. Otherwise, you might want to fix the colnames right within `map_dfr` for each file.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# only get the content of your files
files_content <- file_ls %>%
    map_dfr(~suppressWarnings(read.table(., sep='', header=F, skip=1, fill=T, na.strings = '')))

# only get the headers and keep the longest one
files_headers <- file_ls %>%
    map(~read.table(., sep='', header=F, nrows=1, na.strings = '')) %>%
    .[[which.max(sapply(., length))]]

# rename the columns with that header
files_final <- files_content %>%
    rename_with(.fn = ~as.character(files_headers[.x]), .cols = names(files_headers))
```

// UPDATE:
this is a rework, taking into consideration your problem with multi-line data.
This time around, the code reads each file line by line, then assigns a `real_line_id` based on whether it finds one of `Valid` or `NotEnoughSats`. Then, we glue together the lines that had weirdly been split in your file and only after that we parse through those.

```
library(readr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

files_headers <- file_ls %>%
  map(~read.table(., sep='', header=F, nrows=1, na.strings = '')) %>%
  .[[which.max(sapply(., length))]] %>%
  as.character()

files_final <- file_ls %>%
  map_dfr(
    ~ tibble(
        line_raw = read_lines(., skip = 1)
      ) %>%
      mutate(
        validity = str_extract(line_raw, 'NotEnoughSats|Valid')
      ) %>%
      group_by(real_line_i = cumsum(!is.na(validity))) %>%
      summarise(
        parsed_line = paste(line_raw, collapse = ' ') %>%
          map(
            ~ strsplit(., split = '\\s+') %>%
              unlist() %>%
              setNames(., files_headers[seq_along(.)]) %>%
              as_tibble_row(.name_repair = 'universal')
          ),
        .groups = 'drop'
      ) %>%
      unnest(parsed_line)
  )
```